# What is the replacement of cursor foreach in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is the example scenario

```
 CURSOR cur
    IS
    SELECT Comments,
              Assignee,
              Case_Info,
              Users
            FROM sometable
            where id=:id
OPEN cur 
    LOOP
      v_comments  := NULL;
      v_assignee  := NULL;
      v_case_info := NULL;
      v_users     := NULL;
      FETCH cur INTO v_comments, v_assignee, v_case_info, v_users;
      EXIT

   /* here lopping through each row and get non-null Comments,Assignee,Case_Info,Users values and return one row  */

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cv_mng_data;
```

This whole code is in a funtion used in join with another table. Thie leads to performance issues. i would like to know alternate ways to do this

Comment: "This leads to performance issues. i would like to know alternate ways to do this" - don't use a cursor....

Comment: in the example i have given, i had to loop through each record to find out non-null comment,case_info,assignee.. so i used cursor. please tell me what other ways we can use to solve this

Comment: Do it in `SQL`, no need of `PL/SQL`.

Comment: Yep, do it in SQL to avoid frequent context switches. These have a huge impact on performance. If you really do need PL/SQL for your transformations, consider using BULK COLLECT and FORALL to reduce the amount of context switches.

Answer (score 0):

> *here lopping through each row and get non-null Comments,Assignee,Case_Info,Users values and return one row*

Isn't that simply finding `NOT NULL` values in plain `SQL` -

```
SELECT comments, 
       assignee, 
       case_info, 
       users 
FROM   sometable 
WHERE  id = :id 
       AND comments IS NOT NULL 
       AND assignee IS NOT NULL 
       AND case_info IS NOT NULL 
       AND users IS NOT NULL
```

> *This whole code is in a funtion used in join with another table. Thie leads to performance issues. i would like to know alternate ways to do this*

Why are you wrapping it in a `function`? Why using a `LOOP`? **Row-by-row** is **slow-by-slow**. No need of `PL/SQL` when you could do the same in `SQL`.

Use the above query to join with other tables. If you find performance bottlenecks, then generate the `explain plan` and do the needful.

Comment: Thanks for the response . for one id, there can be 10 records matching. among the 10 records , 1 record might comments null and case_info non null, another record has assignee null, comments non- null. so i will have to pick case_info from one record, comments from another record. The condition comments IS NOT NULL 
       AND assignee IS NOT NULL 
       AND case_info IS NOT NULL 
       AND users IS NOT NULL may not return any matching records

Comment: What kind of logic and design is it? Makes no sense. There is no data integrity. You are randomly picking any NOT NULL value that you encounter from any row for any column.

Comment: It is not randomly picking any NOT NULL value. we will sort by datetime column and pick values from latest record. if the latest record has null value, then we will pick non-value from next latest.I hope you get some idea abt the logic